# knowing the cache attributes through C

Tags: c, caching

I have a black box cache and need to find the associativity and block size,  by writing a C program.

I am running my program on gcc and trying to know the associativity for the system cache. In my program, I have created a huge array, and trying to read all the array elements, which gives me the cache size.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void main()

{
  int array_1[250000], array_2[1000000], array_element;
  int i, j, n;
  clock_t start_1, end_1, start_2, end_2;
  float cpu_time_used, avg_time_per_elem;

  /* Fill the array with data  */
  for(i=0;i<250000;i++)
    array_1[i] = 123;
  for(i=0;i<500000;i++)
    array_2[i] = 123;

  /* To check data integrity  */
  printf("First Array element = %d \n", array_1[0]);
  printf("Middle Array element = %d \n", array_1[124999]);
  printf("Last Array element = %d \n", array_1[249999]);

  /* Start measuring the clock cycles  */
  start_1 = clock();
  printf("\n start = %d\n", start_1);

for(i=0; i<1000;i++)   //number of iterations
  {
    for(j=0; j<250000; j++)  //number of elements
     {
         array_element = array_1[j];
     }
  }

  end_1 = clock();

  printf(" end = %d\n \n", end_1);
  cpu_time_used = end_1 - start_1;
  printf("CPU time used = %.10f ms \n", cpu_time_used);
  cpu_time_used = cpu_time_used/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("\t      = %.6f seconds \n", cpu_time_used);

  /* Calculating the average latency to access the data in cache */
  avg_time_per_elem = cpu_time_used/(i*j);
  printf("Average time to access one element = %.15f seconds = %.6f nanoseconds \n \n \n", avg_time_per_elem, (avg_time_per_elem*1000000000));

  start_2 = clock();
  printf("\n start = %d\n", start_2);

for(i=0; i<2000;i++)   //number of iterations
  {
    for(j=0; j<1000000; j++)  //number of elements
     {
         array_element = array_2[j];
     }
  }

  end_2 = clock();

  printf(" end = %d\n \n", end_2);
  cpu_time_used = end_2 - start_2;
  printf("CPU time used = %.10f ms \n", cpu_time_used);
  cpu_time_used = cpu_time_used/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("\t      = %.6f seconds \n", cpu_time_used);

  /* Calculating the average latency to access the data in cache */
  avg_time_per_elem = cpu_time_used/(i*j);
  printf("Average time to access one element = %.15f seconds = %.6f nanoseconds \n", avg_time_per_elem, (avg_time_per_elem*1000000000));

}
```

Thus, by increasing the array size for every run, I can figure out the L1 cache size to be 32K i.e at the point at which the access time shoots up. But cannot figure out how to find the associativity and block size.

Comment: In the first version of the question, I thought this was an academic exercise where the "black box cache" was somehow separate from the processor's own cache. Characterizing the processor's own cache seems like an impossible task.

Comment: This is indeed an academic task. I have been able to characterize the hit time and miss time of the L1 cache. I have searched through the online resources, but still cannot figure out the feasible way to find the associativity. From the >cpuid command, I can see that the cache size for L1 is 32 K. But verifying it through my program is what I need to do.

Comment: With set associative cache, addresses that are separated by the cache size (32K) should use the same set in the cache. If the cache is 2-way set associative, then two addresses (e.g. 0x1000000 and 0x1008000) should have good performance, but three addresses (0x1000000, 0x1008000, 0x1010000) won't. If the cache is 4-way, then you'll need five addresses before the performance goes down, and so on.

Comment: However, the problem is picking addresses that are otherwise unused. For example, if variable `i` happens to be using the same set as the two addresses that you're testing, then you'll get terrible performance on a 2-way cache.

Comment: @user3386109 has the answer. To pick an appropriate region you need to take the address of a stack variable to find out where your stack is (put your working variables into a struct so you know the alignment) and the address of the current function also. Then either pick one which does or does not coincide with your working data/code.